# Having problems converting jByteArray to .NET byte[ ]

Tags: java-native-interface, c++-cli

I am having problems working with JNI and have been stuck on this issue for quite some time. I have posted about this before, but never received an answer and have done lots of research between now and then.

My JNI signature:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyApplet_invokeManager(JNIEnv *jniEnvPtr, jobject javaObj, jbyteArray encodedData)
```

Some of my code:

```
boolean isCopy;
jbyte* bytes = jniEnvPtr->GetByteArrayElements(encodedData, &isCopy);
jniEnvPtr->ReleaseByteArrayElements(encodedData, bytes, JNI_ABORT);
myManager->ShowQueue(encodedData);
```

The error message:

```
error C2664: 'MyModule::JniToManaged::ShowFormQueue' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'jbyte *' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'
```

I have found no way to convert this to the C# byte[] that I need to pass. I have heard about casting the jbyte* object but can't figure out how to get it into the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to convert a jbytearray to cli::array. Here is the code:

```
jbytearray jArray; //my array
jint len = jniEnvPtr->GetArrayLength(jArray); //get length

boolean isCopy;
jbyte* b = jniEnvPtr->GetByteArrayElements(jArray, &isCopy); //get pointer 
array<byte, 1> ^myArray = gcnew array<byte, 1>(len); //create the cli::array

//loop through jbytearray and copy elements into our cli::array
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = b[i];
}
jniEnvPtr->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jArray, b, JNI_ABORT); // release
```

I also had to convert a jstring to System::String^...

```
jboolean blnIsCopy;
jstring jstrOutput;

//jstring to char*
const char* strA = (jniEnvPtr)->GetStringUTFChars(theJString, &blnIsCopy);

//char* to std::string
std::string standardStr(strA);

//std:string to System::String^
System::String^ str2 = gcnew System::String(standardStr.c_str())
MessageBox(NULL, standardStr.c_str(), "Report Name!", MB_OK);
jniEnvPtr->ReleaseStringUTFChars(theJString, strA);
```

Comment: You should call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` at the end of your conversion or you may cause either the `jstring` object to be pinned indefinitely, leading to memory fragmentation, or the C++ copy to be retained indefinitely, causing a memory leak.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that. I remembered to call it on the jbytearray, just forgot it for the string.

Answer (score -1):

If there are no answers, it means (a) nobody knows, (b) nobody cares (Posting .net stuff under C++ is a sure fire way to get there. Posting an error message that should be easy to fix is another.), or (c) it might be a case of "What the heck is OP trying to do?! This makes  no sense whatsoever. Nope, no head nor tail. Moving on..."

Comment: If I had enough rep, I would vote this down. I honestly don't see the point of even posting this if you have nothing constructive to contribute.